# why unity iap cannot works after import google play games services

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

unity IAP cannot works after import google play games services, it can works before I install google play games services. It success initialized, and no trigger "OnPurchaseFailed" when failed, why?

Here's the code :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

public class Purchaser : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{
    private static IStoreController m_StoreController;          // The Unity Purchasing system.
    private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider; // The store-specific Purchasing subsystems.

    public static string NO_ADS = "no_ads";
    public static string MORE_COIN = "more_coin";

    void Start()
    {
        if (m_StoreController == null)
            InitializePurchasing();

    }

    public void InitializePurchasing()
    {
        if (IsInitialized())
            return;

        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

        builder.AddProduct(NO_ADS, ProductType.NonConsumable);
        builder.AddProduct(MORE_COIN, ProductType.NonConsumable);

        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }

    bool IsInitialized()
    {
        return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
    }

    public void RemoveAds()
    {
        BuyProductID(NO_ADS);
    }

    public void MoreCoin()
    {
        BuyProductID(MORE_COIN);
    }

    void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
                m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
        }
    }

    //IStoreListener

    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        m_StoreController = controller;
        m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;

        //m_StoreController.products.WithID(NO_ADS).metadata.localizedPriceString;
        //m_StoreController.products.WithID(NO_ADS).metadata.isoCurrencyCode;
    }

    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
    {
        // A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, NO_ADS, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            AdManager.instance.RemoveADS();
        else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, MORE_COIN, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MoreCoin", 1);
            Menu.instance.UpdateStore();
        }

        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        // Purchasing set-up has not succeeded. Check error for reason. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
        Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }


    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        // A product purchase attempt did not succeed. Check failureReason for more detail. Consider sharing
        // this reason with the user to guide their troubleshooting actions.
        Debug.Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}", product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please post your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dNcqVNv1
here is it

Comment: Thanks for providing your code. It would be easier if you could minimize the code to where the issue still happens and then place it in your question. Pastebin links might expire.

Comment: m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);

this line nothing happen when call

Comment: Unity IAP demo also cannot works

Answer (score 0):

From the page that's [90% consistent with your code](https://forum.unity.com/threads/closed-how-do-i-track-auto-renewing-subscriptions.476293/#post-3357485):

```
// ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed
// asynchronously.
m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
```

You need to utilize `Debug.Log("got here")` in your `ProcessPurchase` and `OnPurchaseFailed` methods to determine if the purchase worked.

Comment: ProcessPurchase and OnPurchaseFailed both didn't be called

Comment: what is the problem?